# How can I differentiate a bash prompt ending with a newline from a running command?

Tags: bash, readline

I have bracketed-paste-mode turned on in bash. I think it is a good safety feature and I would like to keep it. One problem I have is that it is difficult to differentiate a running command from one where a command ending with a newline was pasted but not run.

That is, my prompt will look like:

```
[...]$ some command that may not output for ten seconds
_
```

(where the `_` indicates where my cursor is)

It is a common error to leave such an unfinished prompt (after pasting in the command) for a long time wondering why it is so slow to execute. Usually when I run `htop` or `ps` in another terminal, I realise that nothing is running and can then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at my prompt.

I would like some way to visually see the difference between the ‘running command’ and ‘still at prompt’ cases. For example beginning all prompt lines with `...>`  or adding some colourful bit of text to my first line like `MULTILINE` if it is the start of a multiline prompt (and deleting that text once the command is executing).

I am using bash 4.2.46 (which seems to use readline version 6) though I would also be ok with answers that only work with bash 4.4.20 (and readline version 7). And I guess I would also be interested in solutions that require newer versions of bash.

Comment: In Bash 5.2.2 in `konsole` in Kubuntu 22.10 whatever I paste (with bracketed paste) gets printed with inverted colors. Upon `Enter` it gets rewritten with normal colors. The problem does not exist. Inverted = pasted but not executed yet; normal = executing.

Comment: You can try playing with the PS1 variable (using online generators is easiest way to do so)  I think you can at worst use command number  to do so and/or using the newline char   etc...    Or you can just finish all your commands with \ just like multiline so you get a ">" waiting for next until you press enter it is displayed that way so  you can distinguish  those prompts from others

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, That’s super helpful to know. I think this might be due to the ‘faces’ feature added in readline 8.